# Как заменить строку на javascript

Tags: javascript

Как заменить название строки, например имеется `span` с классом `new-message` и в этом `span` находится строка "привет". Как сделать поиск по классу и заменить содержимое калсса на другое слово, те я загружаю страницу и если есть класс `new-message` и в нем слово "привет" заменить его на другое слово, конечно что бы выдача страницы была уже с другим словом, как то поиск по DOM и подмену делать, в общем не знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 2):

если вы использоуете JQuery

```
$(".new-message").text('другое слово')
```

Comment: Нет я исползую tempermonkey extension для chrome, оно позволяте подгружать кастомный javascript, и задача в том что бы проверять именно содержимое класса, так как таких калссов много, и если в одном из них есть слово привет заменять его на другое.

Answer (score 2):

Разбейте на подзадачи, и решайте по очереди.

**Найти** все span'ы с классом "new-message" [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

```
var all = document.getElementsByClassName('new-message');
var spans = Array.prototype.filter.call( all, function(el){
    return el.nodeName === 'SPAN';
});
```

**Заменить** в строке подстроку [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
("Привет, как дела?").replace(/привет/ig, 'Здравствуйте');
// Здравствуйте, как дела?
```

**Читать и писать** текстовое содержание элемента – его свойство [`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText):

```
<div id="test">Пустота</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('test').innerText = "Чапаев";
</script>
```

Сумеете объединить всё в рабочее решение самостоятельно?

---

Рабочий **пример** с задержкой в 2 сек.:

```js
function izmena() {
  var all = document.getElementsByClassName('new-message')
     ,spans = Array.prototype.filter.call(
        all,
        function(el){
          return el.nodeName === 'SPAN';
        }
      )
     ,i
  ;
  
  for( i=0; i<spans.length;i++) {
    spans[i].innerText = spans[i]
      .innerText
      .replace(/привет/ig, 'Здравствуйте')
    ;
  }
}

setTimeout( izmena, 2000);
```

```css
body{font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif}
.new-message{display:block;width:200px;border-radius:10px;border:1px solid #EEE;padding:8px;margin:0 0 10px;background-color:#FAE6C9}
```

```html
<span class="new-message">Привет, как дела?</span>
<span class="new-message">Привет!</span>
<span class="new-message">Привет..</span>
<span class="new-message">Привет</span>
<span class="new-message">Пока не родила</span>
<span class="new-message">Что делаешь?</span>
<span class="new-message">Всем привет!</span>
```

Comment: Вроде бы то что нужно, спанов с таким классом множество и в одном из них может быть слово которое нужно подменить, т.е. что бы юзер подрузил станицу уже с подменой, в общем костыль. Объединить пока с трудом, попробую, если вам не сложно буду благодарен.

Comment: Имейте в виду, что сейчас многие страницы формируются динамически – тот же ВКонтакте или Facebook подгружают в страницу сообщения только когда открывается соотв. раздел. Поэтому надо запускать ваш скрипт в нужное время – не сразу по загрузке страницы, а после её наполнения содержанием. Если вы хотите что-то подделать незаметно для юзера вас ждёт провал )

Comment: ну это не совсем подделка, не, речь не о соцсетях)  это пока костыль для лога, есть лог который храниться и когда его запрашивают он подргужает полотно, и на данном этапе некоторые логи нужно подменить